# Перемещением спрайтов при нажатии и удерживании левой кнопки

Tags: xna, c#, разработка-игр

Есть список спрайтов, состоящий из 145 элементов, которые являются объектами класса `UserControlledSprite`

Вот он собственно:

```
class UserControlledSprite : Sprite

{

  MouseState prevMouseState;

   public UserControlledSprite(Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position,Point frameSize, int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize,Vector2 speed)
    : base(textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame,sheetSize, speed)

    {

    }

public UserControlledSprite(Texture2D textureImage, Vector2 position,Point frameSize, int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize,Vector2 speed, int millisecondsPerFrame)

       : base(textureImage, position, frameSize, collisionOffset, currentFrame, sheetSize, speed, millisecondsPerFrame)

   {

   }

    public override Vector2 direction

    {
        get
        {
            Vector2 inputDirection = Vector2.Zero;
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
                inputDirection.X -= 1;
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
                inputDirection.X += 1;
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
                inputDirection.Y -= 1;
            if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
                inputDirection.Y += 1;
            GamePadState gamepadState = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One);
            if (gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X != 0)
                inputDirection.X += gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.X;
            if (gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y != 0)
                inputDirection.Y -= gamepadState.ThumbSticks.Left.Y;
            return inputDirection * speed;
        }
    }

    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
    {
        // Для перемещения спрайта используем direction
        position += direction;
        // Если пользователь переместил курсор мыши, перемещаем спрайт
        MouseState currMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
        if (currMouseState.X != prevMouseState.X ||
        currMouseState.Y != prevMouseState.Y)
        {
            position = new Vector2(currMouseState.X, currMouseState.Y);
        }
        prevMouseState = currMouseState;
        // Если спрайт покинул игровое поле, возвращаем его
        if (position.X < 0)
            position.X = 0;
        if (position.Y < 0)
            position.Y = 0;
        if (position.X > clientBounds.Width - frameSize.X)
            position.X = clientBounds.Width - frameSize.X;
        if (position.Y > clientBounds.Height - frameSize.Y)
            position.Y = clientBounds.Height - frameSize.Y;
        base.Update(gameTime, clientBounds);
    }

}
```

Нужно, нажав на любой спрайт левой кнопкой и удерживая ее, перемещать его в любом направлении

Comment: Пофиксите индусятину в `Vector2 direction {get {...}}`.

`Keyboard.GetState()` вызывается несколько раз, когда достаточно одного.

Comment: я конечно извиняюсь за ламерство, но что такое индусятина :|

Comment: В вашем случае, «индусятина» — нерациональное повторение вызова `Keyboard.GetState()` (до кучи с потенциальными проблемами в случае, если значение этого самого state поменяется в процессе работы функции). Код в стиле индусских программистов.

Comment: Кстати, идея о том, что свойство `direction` зависит от внешнего мира (`GetKeyState`) — плохая. Это никак не свойство, это должна быть вспомогательная (глобальная?) функция.

Comment: все бралось из книги Аарона Рида :О

Comment: Это не лучшим образом говорит об Аароне Риде.

Answer (score 2):

Логика решения вашей задачи:

1. В класс дописываете хэндлер на `Click` (`Tap`, `Drag` или что для конкретно вашей задачи удобнее).
2. В этом хэндлере подписываетесь на событие `MouseMove`
3. В хэндлере `MouseMove` используете `XNA` класс [`Mouse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.mouse_members.aspx):

   ```
   var mouseState = Mouse.GetState();
   var mousePosition = new Point(mouseState.X, mouseState.Y);
   ```
4. Перемещаете спрайт на координаты `mousePosition`.
5. Ну и соответственно обработка `Drag'n'Drop` для спрайта.

Comment: В xna есть событие MouseMove?

Comment: я новичок, совсем новичок ...